# import sql from 'mssql'; console.log(sql); // returns undefined

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, express, nestjs

I am trying to create a CRUD in Nest.js with SQL Server. I have installed the following packages:

`mssql` https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

`@types/mssql` https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mssql

I have created a service `database.service.ts` in which i have the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import sql from 'mssql';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {
  config = {
    user: 'mssql',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'atm',
    options: {
      encrypt: true,
      trustServerCertificate: true,
    },
  };

  async getPool() {
    console.log('SQL obj', JSON.stringify(sql));
    const pool = await sql.connect(this.config);
    return pool;
  }
}
```

In app.controller.ts I have the following:

```
import { DatabaseService } from './database/database.service';
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private db: DatabaseService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello() {
    this.db.getPool().then((pool) => {
      pool
        .request()
        .query('SELECT 1')
        .then((res) => {
          return res;
        });
    });
  }
}
```

I then run `npm run start` and make the following `GET` request with Postman to port 3000:

[image]

As you can see I get nothing in response and also my **Nest.js server has crashed.**

[image]

Complete log:

```
> cajero-backend@0.0.1 start C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend
> nest start

[Nest] 11944  - 09/10/2021 16:11:32     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 11944  - 09/10/2021 16:11:32     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +29ms
[Nest] 11944  - 09/10/2021 16:11:32     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +7ms
[Nest] 11944  - 09/10/2021 16:11:32     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 11944  - 09/10/2021 16:11:32     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +1ms
SQL obj undefined
(node:11944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
    at DatabaseService.getPool (C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\src\database\database.service.ts:19:28)
    at AppController.getHello (C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\src\app.controller.ts:15:13)
    at C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at InterceptorsConsumer.intercept (C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\interceptors\interceptors-consumer.js:11:20)
    at C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:60
    at C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:23
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\cajero\backend\cajero-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:11944) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Something that grabbed my attention is that `sql` is **undefined** in `database.service.ts` How can I fix this?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it!

I added `"esModuleInterop": true,` in tsconfig.json and the problem was solved. Don't know why tho.

Comment: For me it works

Answer (score 0):

try `import * as sql from 'mssql';`

Comment: doesn't work. :(

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 